# iOS app release, image resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a simple, single view iOS app. I have an image which is to be used as the full background. Currently, i have edited the image for both portrait & landscape, in standard (414 X 736) & retina (1242 X 2208) for iPhone 6.

When i use iOS simulator, the background appears fine in all of the devices (4s > 6 plus). However i'm unsure about if this will hold out when launched/released.

Do i need to provide the image in all different resolutions for each device in my final app?

e.g imagePortrait4s.png, imagePortrait5.png, imagePortrait6.png, imagePortrait6plus.png etc

Comment: Have you tested how it looks if the retina version of the image is unavailable?

Comment: yes and it looks fine

Comment: I was thinking that if it looked bad that would at least tell you that you definitely need to. Oh well.

Comment: I guess I'll find out if I need it or not when I submit for approval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your image needs to be the same size as a launch image, your best bet is following the requirements for those: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines - Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2)

Since the documentation does not state that providing the larger images for the iPhone 6 is sufficient to provide a good launch image for older phones, assume you need a 640 x 960 image for the iPhone 4s.